# Remove shadow for angular material mat-icon-button

Tags: angular

I'm trying to remove shadow to this particular button. On click of button the list pop's up

```
      <div>
      <button type="button" mat-icon-button
        (click)="onTogglMenu()">
        <mat-icon svgIcon="add"></mat-icon>
      </button>
     </div>
```

Comment: Can't replicate your problem. Please provide more information. There is no shadow by default in mat button

Comment: yep i have got the solution just added  the below code and it just worked [disableRipple]="true"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have just added this piece of code

[disableRipple]="true"

Answer (score 0):

[disableRipple]='true' Not worked for me
<button mat-raised-button color="custom" (click)="onItemDeleteSelected()"[hidden]="!showDeleteSelected" [disableRipple]="true">delete Delete Selected

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33267032)

Answer (score 0):

You can add class 'mat-elevation-z0' to button. That is used to add elevation on UI elements by adding shadows.

```
<div>
 <button type="button" class="mat-elevation-z0" mat-icon-button (click)="onTogglMenu()">
  <mat-icon svgIcon="add"></mat-icon>
 </button>
</div>
```